# AIX install Mercurial no root

Tags: software-installation, aix

Is is possible to install Mercurial on AIX system without root? I'm an ordinary user of our colleges IBM cluster and in there I fond no version control software.

Could you show a brief guide of how to build mercurial from the source code on AIX?

**Update**
The python on the system is incomplete. When use

```
python setup.py install --user
```

to install Mercurial, I get error

```
"Couldn't import standard bz2 (incomplete Python install)."
```

I also tried to compile python 2.6.8 and get the error:

```
Failed to find the necessary bits to build these modules:
_sqlite3           bsddb185           dl              
imageop            linuxaudiodev      ossaudiodev     
spwd               sunaudiodev                        
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.


Failed to build these modules:
_bsddb             _ctypes            _curses         
_curses_panel      _tkinter           fcntl
```

Comment: Yes, you need root access to install an RPM.

Comment: Do you want Mercurial or git or both?  Those are two completely different systems, with different installation steps.  Please clarify your question to indicate which one(s) you want to use.

Comment: @depquid sorry for confusion, I want Mercurial. I will update the question to make it clear.